# Are there any cases where the reverse of this theorem involving vector space dimensions is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The theorem states that if U is a subspace of a vector space V, with dimV=n, then dimU$\leq$dimV. Are there any cases where dimU$\leq$dimV $\Rightarrow$ U$\leq$V? Maybe if both U and V are subspaces of some other vector space X? And if it is so, then what's the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that such a theorem exists, at least for vector spaces. Consider a real vector space of dimension $n\geq 2$, with a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$. Then $\Bbb Re_1$ and $\Bbb Re_2$ are both subspaces of dimensions $1$, but neither one is a subspace of the other.